# Autofill simple web form and retrieve result

Tags: python, urllib2, autofill

I have a colleague having the task submitting gene sequences of Hepatitis C viruses from patient samples into a request form of a specific website which then identifies mutations which provides information about potential drug resistance.

This is very cumbersome and takes days.

My thought is to automate this with a Python script using `urllib2` (I cannot use mechanize, I have to develop on MAC OS and for reasons I not understand neither `Python setup.py install` nor `pip mechanize install` work - so I am bound to `urllib2`).

My first try was to access the respective website and first submit a sample gene sequence. (On the original website you simple paste the sequence into an entry field named "or paste in" and then press "go".)

On the next page, you will get the result and I want to read out the mutations via regular expressions.

My first try:

```
import url lib
import urllib2

url = 'http://hcv.geno2pheno.org/index.php'
form_data = {'or paste in:': 'CTTCACGGAGGCTATGACGAGGTACTCCGCTCCCCCCGGGGACCCCCCCCAACCAGAATACGACTTGGAGCTCATAACATCGTGCTCCTCTAACGTGTCAGTCGCCCACGACGGCGCTGGAAAAAGGGTCTACTACCTTACCCGTGACCCTACAACCCCCCTCGCAAGAGCTGCGTGGGAGACAGCAAGACACACTCCAGTCAATTCCTGGCTAGGCAACATAATCATGTTTGCCCCCACATTGTGGGCGAGAATGATACTGATGACCCACTTCTTCAGTGTCCTCATCGCCAGGGATCAACTTGAACAGGCCCTTGATTGCGAAATCTACGGAGCCTGCTACTCCATTCAACCACTGGACCTACCTCCAATCATTCAAAGACTCCATGGCCTTAGCGCATTTTCACTCCACAGTTACTCTCCAGGTGAAATCAATAGGGTGGCCGCATGCCTCAGGAAACTTGGGGTCCCGCCCTTGCGAGCTTGGAGACACCGGGCCCGGAGCGTCCGCGCTAAGCTTCTGTCCAGAGGAGGCAGGGCTGCCATATGTGGCAAGTACCTCTTCAATTGGGCAGTAAGAACAAAGCTCAAACTCACTCCAATAGCGGCCGCTGGCCAGCTGGACTTGTCCGGCTGGTTCACGGCTGGCTACAGCGGGGGAGACATTTATCACAGCGTGTCTC'}

params = urllib.urlencode(form_data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
data = response.read()
print data
```

What I get from "data" is the source code from `http://hcv.geno2pheno.org/index.php` and not from the following result page.

Therefore, I have two questions:

1) How can I be sure that my sequence was pasted into the entry field "or paste in:" properly?

2) How do I access the source code of the result page so I can apply regular expressions?

Comment: `pip mechanize install` won't work because you're passing mechanize as the first argument to pip when it should be `pip install mechanize`

Comment: Thanks wilbur! But I still can't install it. It is always stating that I don't have the rights to do it even logged in as Administrator....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going wrong here. First, you need more parameters in your `form_data` dict. Just because you only manually fill in one field doesn't mean that's the only parameter the server needs to complete your request. I've included a `form_data` dict that worked for me below. The main key you're concerned with is 'v3seq'. This is the sequence you want to "paste in".

Then, when you're requesting the page, you need to use a `Request` object and read the response of that request. Looks like this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
url = 'http://hcv.geno2pheno.org/index.php'

form_data = {
    'v3seq': 'CTTCACGGAGGCTATGACGAGGTACTCCGCTCCCCCCGGGGACCCCCCCCAACCAGAATACGACTTGGAGCTCATAACATCGTGCTCCTCTAACGTGTCAGTCGCCCACGACGGCGCTGGAAAAAGGGTCTACTACCTTACCCGTGACCCTACAACCCCCCTCGCAAGAGCTGCGTGGGAGACAGCAAGACACACTCCAGTCAATTCCTGGCTAGGCAACATAATCATGTTTGCCCCCACATTGTGGGCGAGAATGATACTGATGACCCACTTCTTCAGTGTCCTCATCGCCAGGGATCAACTTGAACAGGCCCTTGATTGCGAAATCTACGGAGCCTGCTACTCCATTCAACCACTGGACCTACCTCCAATCATTCAAAGACTCCATGGCCTTAGCGCATTTTCACTCCACAGTTACTCTCCAGGTGAAATCAATAGGGTGGCCGCATGCCTCAGGAAACTTGGGGTCCCGCCCTTGCGAGCTTGGAGACACCGGGCCCGGAGCGTCCGCGCTAAGCTTCTGTCCAGAGGAGGCAGGGCTGCCATATGTGGCAAGTACCTCTTCAATTGGGCAGTAAGAACAAAGCTCAAACTCACTCCAATAGCGGCCGCTGGCCAGCTGGACTTGTCCGGCTGGTTCACGGCTGGCTACAGCGGGGGAGACATTTATCACAGCGTGTCTC',
    'H77Switch': '1',
    'ignore_sgtSwitch': '1',
    'alignwidth': '3',
    'action': '1',
    'go': 'Go',
    'viewResults': '1',
    'viewResSec': 'Prediction'
}

data = urllib.urlencode(form_data)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html_data = response.read()
```

You can then scrape the data from the response and apply your regular expressions. If you're able to get your pip working, I would also suggest taking a look at BeautifulSoup - it's an excellent library for scraping data from html.